# What is the process of uploading and selling my designs on Instagram Avatar Store as a digital fashion creator?

Tags: instagram, requirements, avatar

Instagram Avatar Store provides free and paid garments to wear on the avatar, as an independent digital fashion creator how do I upload my designs to the store so users can try on and buy, what is the process, and the required file types?

Thanks in advance for helping

I have searched across the blogs related to Instagram Avatar store, nothing mentioned about how to participate as a creator, all about how to use it as Instagram user.

I have searched across the meta avatar SDK for something related or even to get the avatar model as something to build on top of it, no results.